# Lowest common multiple for all pairs in a list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have some code that calculates the lowest common multiple for a list of numbers.  I would like to modify this code to return a list of values that represents the lowest common multiple for each pair in my number list.

```
def lcm(numbers):
    return reduce(__lcm, numbers)

def __lcm(a, b):
    return ( a * b ) / __gcd(a, b)

def __gcd(a, b):
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    while b:
        a,b = b,a%b
    return a
```

If the input is `[3, 5, 10]` the output would be `[lcm(5,10)=10, lcm(3,5)=15, lcm(3,10)=30]` (sorting not required).

I feel like there is some elegant way of calculating this list of lowest common multiples but I'm not able to grasp it without some example.

Comment: 30 could be eliminated?  But 3 divides 30 and not 10, 10 divides 30 but not 15.

Comment: Question edited... you have a good point. For the application I am developing 30 can be eliminated, but the reason for that is not clear or in scope for this question.

Comment: I'm confused.  Your code as it is now outputs 30 for the list [3, 5, 10]?  You want it to output [lcm(5,10)=10, lcm(3,5)=15, lcm(3,10)=30]?  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have looks good.  I'd only change how you produce the answer:

```
def lcm(numbers):
    return map(__lcm, combinations( numbers, 2 ) )
```

where I'm using [combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from itertools.

Answer (score 3):

Given your existing functions (with __gcd() edited to return a, rather than none):

```
from itertools import combinations

inlist = [3, 5, 10]

print [lcm(pair) for pair in combinations(inlist, 2)]
```

Comment: Also, if you want to eliminate duplicates in the input list: print [lcm(pair) for pair in combinations(set(inlist), 2)]